# Unable to read file name of uploaded file as UTF-8

Tags: servlets, character-encoding, filenames, apache-commons-fileupload

I'm trying to read the video name in servlet, if the video name is in english i can read it fine, if the video name is in arabic i couldn't read it as expected

```
if (!item.isFormField()) {

                        String value = (String) item.getName();
                        String videoName = new String(
                                value.getBytes("iso-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
                        if (videoName != "")
                            item.write(new File(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY
                                    + videoName));
                        arrayList.add(videoName);
```

however is working if the item is not form field

```
else if (item.isFormField()) {
                        String inputName = (String) item.getFieldName();

                            String value = (String) item.getString();
                            value = new String(
                                    value.getBytes("iso-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
                            hashMap.put(inputName, value);

                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by adding `req.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");`